# Improve the runtime of an algorithm that returns number of rounds to collect numbers in a perm in ascending order

Tags: python, runtime

Given a list of random nonnegative integers from 0 to n inclusive, this program is supposed to count how many rounds it takes to collect them in ascending order.

For example, [0,4,3,5,2,1] takes 4 rounds (0,1, then 2, then 3, then 4 and 5). When when running through a tester file, the CPU goes off the charts. I can't see any loose ends.

```
def collect_numbers(perm):
  inv = invert(perm)
  rounds = 0
  for i in range(len(perm)-1):
    if inv[i] - inv[i+1] < 0:
      continue
    else:
      rounds += 1
  return rounds + 1

def invert(perm):
  return [perm.index(l) for l in range(len(perm))]
```

Comment: With the info you've given I can run this function in 2.55 µs. What kind of performance do you need? Your `invert()` function is O(n**2) which could probably be better.

Comment: That's plenty. Can't seem to get the same on my end.

Comment: I think you're misrepresenting [the task](https://github.com/ikokkari/PythonProblems/blob/main/109%20Python%20Problems%20for%20CCPS%20109.pdf). The answer for that case is 4 because you collect 0,1, then 2, then 3, then 4,5. Your code might actually be doing the right thing, though, so it's not clear whether you misunderstood the task or just didn't describe it well here.

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes, that's what I meant. Example has been edited accordingly.

Comment: Which page is the exercise on?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark Page 38. Name is "Collecting numbers", and the function name `collect_numbers` also appears there.